# SQL update by groups?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'd like to update approximately the first X number of rows in a table but I want to always update all rows with a matching column at the same time.  So if my table has:

```
MyID   Transaction   Amount   Date         Status
1      1             2        02/08/2016   0
1      1             4        02/08/2016   0
2      4             1        02/08/2016   0
2      3             2        02/08/2016   0
3      10            1        02/08/2016   0
3      6             4        02/08/2016   0
```

I want to update Status to 1 on approximately the first 5 rows, but I don't want to split up matching MyID values, how can I do that?  I could update the first 4 or 6 in this example.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one method:

```
update t
    set status = 1
    where myId in (select top 5 MyId from t order by MyId);
```

Comment: would the sub query return values the `in()` would understand? PS. I did not downvote

Comment: Nice solution @Gordon.

Comment: @Coderchu . . . Of course.  That is how `in` with subqueries work.

Comment: Is the "order by MyId" needed?  It doesn't seem like it.  Would a "group by MyId" instead make it any more efficient since duplicates would be eliminated?

Comment: @PeaceDog . . . SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no such thing as the first 5 rows, unless a column specifies the ordering.  From the context of your query, I guessed that `myId` was that column.